# Python output when started from another proccess

Tags: c#, python, file-io

I have GUI controller, written on C# WPF, which run python script with args. There are some prints and writes to file in this python script. I redirect stdout and stderr outputs to the TextBlock. But no one of this outputs doesn't work. Any Ideas?

C# runner:

```
...
pr.StartInfo.FileName = pythonPath;
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = scriptPath + " " + args;
pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
pr.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pr.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(sortErrorHandler);
pr.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(sortOutputHandler);
pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
//pr.Exited += new EventHandler(whenExitProcess);
TB.Text = "";
pr.Start();
pr.BeginOutputReadLine();
pr.BeginErrorReadLine();                
}
e.Handled = true;
}



private void sortErrorHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        { 
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
                {
                    TB.Text += outLine.Data + Environment.NewLine;

                }
            }));

    }
    private void sortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {            
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {                   
                TB.Text += outLine.Data + Environment.NewLine;                   
            }
        }));

    }
```

Python:

```
print "Hello"
file.open("test", "a")
file.write("Hello again")
file.close()
... remaining code
```

Okay, sys.stderr.write("test") is working, but what difference may be between stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just not getting any data, you may need to call `sys.stdout.flush()` (and/or `sys.stderr.flush()`) in your python script.

I'm unclear if you're saying there's also a problem with writing to a file.

Comment: It was worth a shot. That's really the only potential problem the python code might have, so I think the solution is going to be somewhere in your C# code. And I definitely can't help you there...